# Oracle --> Postgres query

Tags: oracle, postgresql, subquery

I'm an Oracle guy trying to convert a query like this to Postgres.  Not really understanding all the syntax, etc.   Was hoping someone can help?

Oracle Query:

```
    SELECT c.code, c.recommendation, s.suggested, s.sugg_by, a.approved, a.app_by
    FROM (SELECT code, recommendation FROM recommendations) c,
         (SELECT code, suggested, sugg_by FROM suggestions) s,
         (SELECT code, approved, app_by FROM suggestions) a
    WHERE c.code = s.code(+)
      AND c.code = a.code(+);
```

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT c.code, c.recommendation, s.suggested, s.sugg_by, a.approved, a.app_by
FROM (SELECT code, recommendation FROM recommendations) c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT code, suggested, sugg_by FROM suggestions) s on c.code = s.code
LEFT JOIN (SELECT code, approved, app_by FROM suggestions) a ON c.code = a.code
```

You seem like didn't need to use subquery, because you didn't do anything in the subquery only select original columns. you can query the table directly.

```
SELECT
    c.code,
    c.recommendation, 
    s.suggested,
    s.sugg_by, 
    a.approved,
    a.app_by
FROM recommendations c 
LEFT JOIN suggestions s on c.code = s.code
LEFT JOIN suggestions a ON c.code = a.code
```

Comment: IIRC the `(+)` is a `LEFT JOIN`